# How to keep Explorer from popping up while using VDS to format volumes

Tags: explorer, ntfs, vds

I'm using VDS to create and format volumes.  Everything works well, except Explorer keeps popping up asking to format (right before my code does the format), or it'll pop up a window to the volume shortly after format

is there a way simmer Explorer down, during the VDS operations?

Comment: Does your code look similar to https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/CppVDSFormatVolume-c84cb6f2/?